# Bootstrap custom ajax modal

Tags: bootstrap-modal

Refering to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313992/dynamically-build-twitter-bootstrap-modal) topic, I created ajax modal:

```
MAIN JS FILE
(function ($)
{

    $.fn.ajaxmodal = function (options)
    {
        var defaults = {
            title: "", 
            content: $("<p />"),
            id: "ajaxmodal", 
            open: function () { }, 
        };
        var settings = $.extend(true, {}, defaults, options);

        if (settings.js){
            var js = document.createElement("script");
            js.id = "script"+settings.id;
            js.type = "text/javascript";
            js.innerHTML += settings.js;        
        }
        if (settings.css){
            var css = document.createElement("style");
            css.id = "style"+settings.id;
            css.type = "text/css";
            css.innerHTML += settings.css;      
        }       
        // create the DOM structure
        var $modal = $("<div />").attr("id", settings.id).attr("role", "dialog").addClass("modal fade").attr("data-keyboard", "false").attr("data-backdrop", "static")
                        .append($("<div />").addClass("modal-dialog")
                            .append($("<div />").addClass("modal-content")
                                .append($("<div />").addClass("modal-header")
                                    .append($("<h4 />").addClass("modal-title").text(settings.title)))
                                .append($("<div />").addClass("modal-body")
                                    .append(settings.content))
                            )
                        );
        $modal.shown = false;
        this.dismiss = function ()
        {
           if (!$modal.shown)
            {
                window.setTimeout(function ()
                {
                    $modal.dismiss();
                }, 50);
                return;
            }
            $modal.modal("hide");
            $modal.prev().remove();
            $modal.empty().remove();
            $("body").removeClass("modal-open");
            if (settings.js){ $("#script"+settings.id).remove(); }
            if (settings.css){ $("#style"+settings.id).remove(); }
        }
        $modal.find(".modal-header").prepend($("<button />").attr("type", "button").addClass("close").html("&times;").click(function () { $modal.dismiss() }));
        settings.open($modal);

        $modal.on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
            $modal.shown = true;
            if (settings.js){ $("body").append(js); }
            if (settings.css){ $("body").append(css); }
        });
        $modal.modal("show");       

        return $modal;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

I load content via jq/php

```
MAIN JS FILE:
    $(document).on('click', '.open_modal', function() {
        var a = 'my..vars...';
        $.post("/ajax_modal.php", a, function(o){
            if(o.s){
                 // open modal
                $.fn.ajaxmodal(o.o);

            } else {
                 // invalid access
                $.notify(o.m);
            }
        },'json');  
    }); 

AJAX.PHP:
            $obj = array(
                'title' => 'My title',
                'content' => '

            <div class="box">
                <button type="button" class="btn clickme">Button</button>
            </div>
            <div class="box2">          
                content
            </div>              

                ',
                'id' => 'modal-'.$id,
                'js' => '
$(document).on("click", ".clickme", function() {
    var a = "my..vars..";
    $.post("/ajax_modal.php", a, function(o){
        if(o.s){
            //  
            //      PROBLEM
            //
            $.fn.ajaxmodal.dismiss;
            $.notify(o.m);
        } else {
            // dismiss modal
            $.notify(o.m);
        }
    },"json"); 
}); 

                        ',
                'css' => '
.box {display: block; width: 100%;}
                '

                );

            $out = array(
                's'=>1,
                'o'=>$obj
            );
            echo json_encode($out);
```

Via ajax I create modal and inject content and CSS & JS into body, and  problem is that function for closing modal is not working ( $.fn.ajaxmodal.dismiss; or $.fn.ajaxmodal.dismiss(); doesnt work) to close modal and remove content and scripts from body. I have tried

```
IN MAIN JS
            if(o.s){
                var ajax_mod = $.fn.ajaxmodal(o.o);

            } else {    

AND IN ajax.php
        if(o.s){
            ajax_mod.dismiss();
//          OR
//          ajax_mod.dismiss;
            $.notify(o.m);
        } else {
```

But that doesnt work either.. How can I make this work ?

Comment: Please refer to the documentation of the bootstrap-modal tag on stackoverflow it self.

Comment: this is a custom plugin, it cant be done using defult settings..

Comment: Yes this is a custom plugin but it will give you many advantages like multiple popup at same time without any extra efforts and we don't even need to write modal div our self and it will also be destroyed upon closing so no need to worry about conflicts.

Comment: Yes but key features (what I need) is to inject .js and .css code, and also to remove them on close..

Comment: Nothing bootstrap dialog js will take care of it it self. just refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42941539/modal-bootstrap-visible/42956661#42956661 . copy past snippet into html file and run in browser. And check  elements in developer mode in browser.